# What's wrong with my bevel

Tags: bevel

***Question 01:***

[image]

As the images shown below, I tried many times and I still can't bevel successfully no matter I choose edges or faces, and I don't know what's wrong with it, anyone can help me with this?
[image]

[image]

P.S: A few friends commented below that let me try pressing M, but M in my blender means to move to collections, it doesn't work for this situation

---

***Question 02:***

[image]
When I added a bevel modification on the object to get more gap like the last image, it turned out to be like the following images, does anyone know what the wrong is with this situation?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, try a M > Merge by Distance and also a Shift N in order to recalculate the normals

Comment: ...and select all with `A` before you are merging and recalculating.

Comment: ...and if it still doesn't work with the aforementioned suggestions, i suggest you share a blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I remodeled the object, and it worked

Comment: But M means move to the collection in my blender

Comment: M is context-sensitive. I Object Mode it means Move to collection. In Edit Mode, it means Megre <by option>.  Is this object under a Boolean modifier.. Please share as suggested.

Comment: Thanks， I got it

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I applied the boolean before merge, and as you said, select all with A and press M/Merge by Distance, and then Shift N with no reaction, at last, I got a new copy of it, it can be beveled but I can't bevel on it like the original cylinder, the bevel was limited in a small amount

Comment: @moonboots  I got a new copy of it after I finished all the steps as you and Gordon said, select all with A in edit mode, press M>Merge by distance, and then press Shift N with no reaction. The copy can be beveled but I can't bevel on it like you did in my other post, the bevel was limited to a small amount, and I don't know why

Comment: Because the bevel probably make some faces overlap, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots I think I solved this problem following your step, click off the clamp overlap to get more bevel amount and manually fix the vertexes which makes the surfaces broken, right?

Comment: You can do that, make sure that it works with the Clamp Overlap option on